# cordova prompt by default not focus on the text area

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, extjs, sencha-touch

I m using cordova prompt in Ext js mobile app like that

```
navigator.notification.prompt('Please enter your value',  me.onPrompt(),  'Target',  ['ok', 'cancel'] );
```

It's working on android version 5.

But above android version 5 the text area is not focusing input box.when user touches that dialogue box is focusing.
I need without touch it should be focusing.

anyone can suggest me a better solution

Answer (score 1):

There's a pull request on the official [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/pull/132) page of the cordova dialog plugin addressing this issue. This PR added

`promptInput.requestFocus();`

to Notification.java.

This is not a complete answer but might help you to get closer to it.